# How to insert instance variable as css rule in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I've got AR class:

```
.........
  store :skin_properties, accessors: [
    :background_color,
    :font_size,
    :font_family,
    :color
  ]
.........
```

Which save values in this way:

```
{"background_color"=>"#f2f2f2", "font_size"=>"20px", "font_family"=>"Verdana", "color"=>"#000000"}
```

How can I insert it in **edit.haml** file as inline css?

I tried something like this, but it's not working ...

```
:sass
  body
    -@user.skin_properties.each_with_index do |(k,v)|
      "#{k.gsub("_","-")}:#{v};"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody, came up with something like this:

```
- css = @user.skin_properties.map {|k,v| "#{k.dasherize}: #{v};" }.join("\n")
%style== body { #{css} }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the hash to a `style` property of some tag.

Example: change

`{"background_color"=>"#f2f2f2"}`

to

`style: {'background-color: #f2f2f2'}`

Answer (score 1):

You are silently running ruby code(i.e. using `-`, instead of `=`).

Also, try using [`dasherize`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/dasherize) for such case:

```
:sass
    body
       = @user.skin_properties.map{|k,v| "#{k.dasherize}: #{v};" }.join
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do it this way. I don't use haml so you'll need to convert it yourself:

```
:sass
  body
    <% @user.skin_properties.each_with_index do |(k,v)| %>
      <%= "#{k.gsub("_","-")}:#{v};" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: A bit nit picky, but what do you think about using `sub` over `gsub` for a little speed boost, since it looks like each property only contains at most 1 underscore.

Comment: Yes I think you're right, `sub` would be a bit more efficient since you are only substituting one character instead of changing all characters with the global `gsub`. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
:sass
    body
       =@user.skin_properties.map{|k,v| "#{k.gsub("_","-")}:#{v};" }.join
```

Comment: You should give some explanation for your answer.